# HP ProLiant MicroServer drivers for windows XP

Tags: windows

hi i recently purchased a HP ProLiant MicroServer, started off by installing windows 7 and it installed correctly including the drivers. but now i downgraded my system to windows XP and i cnt install any drivers cause the system does not support them. could you kindly please tell me where i can find the network, vga, audio and chipset drivers for HP Proliant MicroServer running Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

Xp is not [supported by HP on that model](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=4248036&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&query=%20ProLiant%20MicroServer&tool=) you will have to identify and find them on your own.

You might try [this software solution](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html)

Or use this manual method to [identify and find drivers](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/)

Comment: +1 Unknown device Identifier has helped me serveral times.